# Usar o botão de voltar do hardware para outra função

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Tenho um app com várias Activitys, sempre que eu mudo de Activity eu executo os seguintes comandos:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar2.this, excluir.class);
                intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabbanco);
                intent.putExtra("pagina", page2);
                startActivity(intent);
                gerenciar2.this.finish();
```

Problema é que quando executo o undo do hardware do android ele fecha a ultima Activity aberta assim fechando a aplicação.

Então deixei de executar o comando `MainActivity.this.finish();` somente na minha atividade principal, assim quando o usuário utilizar o undo ele retorna para a atividade principal.

Blz, até ai tudo certo.

Problema é que passo varias vezes para a minha atividade principal e vai abrindo uma em cima da outra toda vez que mudo de Activity.

Necessito executar o `startActivity(intent);` para passar os parâmetros atualizados, então queria que antes de eu fazer o `startActivity(intent);` eu executasse um método que feche a Activity main antes de eu cria-la novamente.
pesquisei e não achei nada a respeito, então gostaria que alguém me desse uma alternativa a isso.
agradeço!

o que eu queria era poder fazer ao apertar o botão voltasse de dela e ao chegar na principal perguntar se quero sair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu percebi bem tu não precisas andar a criar a *Activity* *main* sempre que lá retornas, basta usar os métodos `onRestoreInstanceState` e `onSaveInstanceState` para passares os dados de um lado para o outro sem fazer *start* e *finish* da *Activity*.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    conf = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("conf");
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    tabbanco = savedInstanceState.getExtra("tabbanco");

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();

    outState.putExtra("tabbanco", tabbanco);

}
```

Comment: [Esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40049/7210) complementa a minha.

Answer (score 2):

Com grande ajuda do jorge, cheguei no seguinte eu reescrevi a função `public void onBackPressed()` para voltar de tela.

assim:

```
public void onBackPressed()  {
    Intent iplay = new Intent(paginadeedicao.this, MainActivity.class);
    iplay.putExtra("pagina2", page2);
    iplay.putExtra("tabbanco", tabbanco);
    startActivity(iplay);
    paginadeedicao.this.finish();
}
```

e ao chegar na principal executei o seguinte:

```
public void onBackPressed()  {
    AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
    mensagem.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair?");
    mensagem.setIcon(R.drawable.sair);

    mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            fechabanco();
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }});
    mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",null);
    mensagem.show();

}
```

Obrigado Jorge!